# Блоки разной высоты css

Tags: css

Есть такой макет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы блоки были друг под другом, не нарушая сетки бустрап?

верстаю его с помощью бутстрап сетки, чтобы потом удобней было адаптировать, дальше три колонки должны перейти в две и т.д.

Пробовал сделать с помощью flex-a, на дескоптном дизайне получилось все, ограничив высоту родительского блока, но высоту в ручную подбирал. А вот уже для расширения 1024 как-то не получается, там у меня уже идут две колонки и высоту не могу подобрать.

Различные jquery плагины пробовал, но как-то не осилил настроить.

Как реализовать так, чтобы блоки разной высоты были друг под другом?

Comment: добавьте пример разметки и стилей которые вы пытались

Comment: Блоки в разметке должны идти горизонтально или вертикально?

Answer (score 1):

Смотри в сторону свойств `column-count` и `column-gap`. Вот [документация](http://htmlbook.ru/css/column-count).